# JSONObject is Null when returned

Tags: php, android

While researching the problem I came across ([Returned JSONObject is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694627/returned-jsonobject-is-always-null)) this question and applied the accepted answer to my code. It did work when I tested it twice in a row however woke up in the morning to test it final time an move on and it's began to return null again.

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once("C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\tablet-secure.php");
require_once("_functions.php");
$db=sqlsrv_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_CONNECTION);

if($db)
{

    if (!empty($_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_appliance_id']) && !empty($_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_appt_id']) &&
        !empty($_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_eng_sig']) && !empty($_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_date']))
    {
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fl_atms_fan_assst_fan_diltn_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fl_atms_fan_assst_fan_diltn_chk']; 
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_vent_sz_h_l_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_vent_sz_h_l_chk']; 
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_wat_fuel_snd_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_wat_fuel_snd_chk'];
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_elec_fus_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_elec_fus_chk']; 
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_correct_valv_arrng_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_correct_valv_arrng_chk']; 
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_isol_avail_elec_fuel_1met_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_isol_avail_elec_fuel_1met_chk'];
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_boilr_plntrm_cln_clr_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_boilr_plntrm_cln_clr_chk']; 
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_heat_exch_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_heat_exch_chk']; 
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_ignit_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_ignit_chk'];             
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_gas_vlv_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_gas_vlv_chk'];             
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fan_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fan_chk'];             
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_safety_dev_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_safety_dev_chk'];           
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_control_box_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_control_box_chk'];             
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_brnrs_pilot_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_brnrs_pilot_chk'];             
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fuel_press_typ_chk = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fuel_press_typ_chk'];           
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_burner_wshd_clnd_opn = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_burner_wshd_clnd_opn'];           
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_pilot_assmbl_clnd_adjst_opn = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_pilot_assmbl_clnd_adjst_opn'];             
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_ignition_sysem_clnd_adjst_opn = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_ignition_sysem_clnd_adjst_opn'];             
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_brner_fan_airway_clnd_opn = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_brner_fan_airway_clnd_opn'];             
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_heat_exch_flu_cln_clr_opn = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_heat_exch_flu_cln_clr_opn'];             
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fuel_elec_supp_conn_snd_opn = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fuel_elec_supp_conn_snd_opn'];         
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_intrlck_in_plc_opn = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_intrlck_in_plc_opn'];       
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_appliance_id  = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_appliance_id'];      // foreign key
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_appt_id = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_appt_id'];     // foreign key
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_eng_sig = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_eng_sig']; 
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_date = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_date']; 
        $orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_notes = $_POST['orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_notes'];


        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_orders_certs_gas_svc_rec 
            (orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fl_atms_fan_assst_fan_diltn_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_vent_sz_h_l_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_wat_fuel_snd_chk,
            orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_elec_fus_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_correct_valv_arrng_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_isol_avail_elec_fuel_1met_chk,
            orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_boilr_plntrm_cln_clr_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_heat_exch_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_ignit_chk,
            orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_gas_vlv_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fan_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_safety_dev_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_control_box_chk,
            orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_brnrs_pilot_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fuel_press_typ_chk,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_burner_wshd_clnd_opn, 
            orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_pilot_assmbl_clnd_adjst_opn,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_ignition_sysem_clnd_adjst_opn,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_brner_fan_airway_clnd_opn,
            orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_heat_exch_flu_cln_clr_opn,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fuel_elec_supp_conn_snd_opn,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_intrlck_in_plc_opn,
            orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_appliance_id,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_appt_id,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_eng_sig,orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_date,
            orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_notes)";

        $sql.=" VALUES ('"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fl_atms_fan_assst_fan_diltn_chk)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_vent_sz_h_l_chk)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_wat_fuel_snd_chk)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_elec_fus_chk)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_correct_valv_arrng_chk)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_isol_avail_elec_fuel_1met_chk)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_boilr_plntrm_cln_clr_chk)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_heat_exch_chk)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_ignit_chk)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_gas_vlv_chk)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fan_chk)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_safety_dev_chk)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_control_box_chk)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_brnrs_pilot_chk)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fuel_press_typ_chk)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_burner_wshd_clnd_opn)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_pilot_assmbl_clnd_adjst_opn)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_ignition_sysem_clnd_adjst_opn)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_brner_fan_airway_clnd_opn )."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_heat_exch_flu_cln_clr_opn)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_fuel_elec_supp_conn_snd_opn)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_intrlck_in_plc_opn)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_appliance_id)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_appt_id)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_eng_sig)."',
        '"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_date)."','"._FormatStr4Qry($orders_certs_gas_svc_rec_notes)."')";

            if ($res=sqlsrv_query($db,$sql,array(),array("Scrollable"=>'static')))
                { 

                    // successfully inserted into database
                    $response["success"] = 1;
                    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

                    // echoing JSON response
                    echo json_encode($response);
                } 
            else 
                {
                    // failed to insert row
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

                    // echoing JSON response
                    echo json_encode($response);
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }
            sqlsrv_close($db);
    }   
    else
        {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "fill in required fields.";


        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
        }
}
else
{
    echo "could not connect to database";
}
?>
```

Java class:

```
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_operations,
                "POST", params);


       // writing response to log
          Log.d("Create Response:", json.toString());  // return as null
```

JSONParser:

```
package com.example.newdatabase;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class JSONParser {

InputStream is = null;
JSONObject jObj = null;
String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST")
        {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();


        }
        else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF_8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try 
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF_8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
       is.close();

        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);   // added this line as stated on the accepted answer on the above linked quesition.
    }

     catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object

            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    // return JSON String

    return jObj;

 }
}
```

Logcat:

```
07-18 10:08:59.090: E/Buffer Error(29965): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at com.example.newdatabase.ChecksAndOperations$NewChecksAndOperations.doInBackground(ChecksAndOperations.java:1305)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at com.example.newdatabase.ChecksAndOperations$NewChecksAndOperations.doInBackground(ChecksAndOperations.java:1)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-18 10:08:59.115: E/AndroidRuntime(29965):    ... 4 more
```

Regarding the `Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null`, 
I have tried activating the `StrictMode` however that seems to not make any difference.

I'm sure everything is perfect in the code is fine. it just works when it wants to.

Comment: is your query returning some string. post your logcat output.

Comment: When it works it does output the messages of `[success]` (stated in `PHP` code). I'm just waiting for the logcat to output the error as it takes some time.

Comment: please check the edit as you requested

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post_variable", YOUR_VARIABLE));  

JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            POST_COMMENT_URL, "POST", params);

                    // full json response
                    Log.d("Post sending...", json.toString());

                    // json success element
                    success = json.getInt(PHP_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("Post Added!", json.toString());    
                        finish();
                        return json.getString(PHP_SUCCESS);
                    }else{
                        Log.d("Error!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                        return json.getString(PHP_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, was on lunch. Which `YOUR_VARIABLE` you referring to here please ?

Comment: What do you want to post?

Comment: Oh ok.My AsyncTask is `static` therefore, isn't allowing me to use `finish()` ?

Comment: In my project AsyncTask is not static so I can use `finish()`

Comment: Nope. Still trying every way I and other can think of

Comment: In my project why did it happen i dont know but your situation happened to me. I just delete my database and create again and it worked after redesigned. Maybe you can do it.

Comment: You mean delete and redesign the remote database ?

Comment: If it is a small database, you create everything from the beginning. You dont lose anything to try this way. Before do that, export whole database as sql and then delete everything.

Comment: It's not a small one. However, just going to try deleting and create that specific table from scratch again. Fingerscross!